# Is there a SOLR equivalent to postgres's "explain analyze"?

Tags: performance, solr

I'm looking into why certain SOLR calls are slow and for postgres there's this really neat tool that explains what happens for a query.

Can't seem to find the same thing for SOLR, though maybe I'm missing something?

Most of what I've found just suggests more heapspace, use SSDs, shard your index more...

And those are all very general things, nothing that allows me to look into specifics, which is what I'm looking for.

What is possible in terms of such researching of why a SOLR query is slow?

Comment: A good starting point is appending `debug=all` to your query - that should at least give you some information about exactly how your query is being parsed and what the number of documents each term end up as; usually the expensive parts of a query are those that have to be evaluated for each term in the index, i.e. it can't used an actual index properly.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks. It's not doing much though. Turns out most my queries are using `MatchAllDocsQuer("*:*")` with filters on it. I'm seeing no details on it, just how the spent time is split over the query and faceting. I'll look further. And just in case: no, I can't share the queries, sorry.